# error while creating trigger on update operation in mysql5?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I am creating a trigger on update operation. However, while creating trigger in MySQL5 it is giving an error.

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test`.`Employee_Trigger_Update`
     AFTER UPDATE ON `test`.`employee`
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     INSERT into `test`.`Employee_log`
     (id,description)
     VALUES 
     (old.id, CONCAT('Id with '
                       , old.id
                       ,' is modified from '
                       , OLD.start_date
                       , ' to '
                       , NEW.start_date)    );
```

**Error**

> Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 8 (0 ms taken)

If some one could please help it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I just answered a question with the same problem 2 min ago. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013246/how-to-create-a-trigger-for-delete-php-myadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different delimiter other than semicolon

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `test`.`Employee_Trigger_Update`
     AFTER UPDATE ON `test`.`employee`
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     INSERT into `test`.`Employee_log`
     (id,description)
     VALUES 
     (old.id, CONCAT('Id with ',old.id,' is modified from ',OLD.start_date, ' to ', NEW.start_date));
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: now i am getting error- Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END $$
DELIMITER' at line 1
(0 ms taken)

Answer (score 1):

one thing i see , you dont have - `END;` in the end of trigger declare , see examples and documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: i have used "END ;" at the end of query but now it is giving error -Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
(0 ms taken)